# Compile Error At IfError in VBA Code of Nested WorksheetFunctions

Tags: vba, compiler-errors, excel-2016, worksheet-function

So, I'm quite new to VBA and I'm trying to learn.  I have several tables with fastener data that I'm trying to pull information from based on what's in the main input table.  I have a formula that works, but as I add different fastener tables, the nested IF formula is getting unruly.  I decided to try to convert the formula to VBA and I'm getting an error: "Compile error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment."  It shows up at the IfError.  I may also have called the table columns incorrectly.  The formula that I am trying to convert is included below.  I haven't yet determined how best to set up the If statement so that if the user selected IFF, it would switch to using the IFF table, but that's another post.

```
 Dim tbl_Solid As ListObject
    
    Dim Rep_Fast_Type
    Dim Incoming_Dia
    Dim BP_Max_Dia
    Dim Test_Dia
    Dim Rep_Fast
    Dim Test_Value
    Dim i
    
    Set tbl_Solid = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Fastener DB").ListObjects("tbl_Solid")
    
    i = 1
    
    Incoming_Dia = [tbl_Input].Cells(i, 2)
    BP_Max_Dia = [tbl_Input].Cells(i, 3)
    Rep_Fast_Type = [tbl_Input].Cells(i, 4)
    
    If Incoming_Dia > BP_Max_Dia Then
            Test_Dia = Incoming_Dia
        Else
            Test_Dia = BP_Max_Dia
    End If
    
'Compile error at IfError in third line.
    If Rep_Fast_Type = "Solid" Then
       Rep_Fast = WorksheetFunction.Index([tbl_Solid].Range("Fastener"), _
                WorksheetFunction.Aggregate(15, 6, WorksheetFunction.IfError( _
                    Rows([tbl_Solid].Range("Fastener")) / ((Test_Dia >= [tbl_Solid].Range("min")) * (Test_Dia <= [tbl_Solid].Range("max"))), _
                        Rows([tbl_Solid].Range("Fastener")) / (Test_Dia <= [tbl_Solid].Range("min")), 1)))
    End If
    
    'To test values
    MsgBox "Incoming diameter is " & Incoming_Dia & vbCrLf & "B/P max diameter is " & BP_Max_Dia & vbCrLf & "Test diameter is " & Test_Dia & vbCrLf & "Repair fastener type is " & Rep_Fast_Type & vbCrLf & "Repair Fastener is " & Rep_Fast
```

Old Excel Formula:

```
=IF([@[rep type]]="Solid",INDEX(tbl_Solid[[#All],[Fastener]],AGGREGATE(15,6,IFERROR(ROW(tbl_Solid[Fastener])/(([@diameter]>=tbl_Solid[min])*([@diameter]<=tbl_Solid[max])),ROW(tbl_Solid[Fastener])/([@diameter]<=tbl_Solid[min])),1)),IF([@[rep type]]="IFF",INDEX(tbl_IFF[[#All],[Fastener]],AGGREGATE(15,6,IFERROR(ROW(tbl_IFF[Fastener])/(([@diameter]>=tbl_IFF[min])*([@diameter]<=tbl_IFF[max])),ROW(tbl_IFF[Fastener])/([@diameter]<=tbl_IFF[min])),1))))
```

Screenshot of Data
[image: Screenshot of Data]

Comment: I'm not sure that formula is convertible like that. You may have to use `Evaluate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a parenthesis wrongly placed:

replace this line:

```
Rows([tbl_Solid].Range("Fastener")) / (Test_Dia <= [tbl_Solid].Range("min")), 1)))
```

with for this:

```
Rows([tbl_Solid].Range("Fastener")) / (Test_Dia <= [tbl_Solid].Range("min"))), 1))
```

Nevertheless, I would suggest to use the [With statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement) to wrap the formula, i.e.:

```
With WorksheetFunction
    Rep_Fast = .Index([tbl_Solid].Range("Fastener"), _
        .Aggregate(15, 6, .IfError( _
            Rows([tbl_Solid].Range("Fastener")) / _
                ((Test_Dia >= [tbl_Solid].Range("min")) * (Test_Dia <= [tbl_Solid].Range("max"))), _
                    Rows([tbl_Solid].Range("Fastener")) / (Test_Dia <= [tbl_Solid].Range("min"))), 1))
End With
```

*Note that this answer refers only to the syntax that gives the compile error, no test have been performed to the formula output.*

Comment: Thanks, that got rid of the subject error, but now its telling me that I have a run-time error 5 at [tbl_Solid].Range("Fastener").  I'm not sure how to call a column from a named table.

Comment: That seems to belong to a new question. I suggest to open a new question but not just refer to this problem, explain what your are trying to achieve and why your are using this method instead of just an standard formula, which may have to do with how the result of the formula in going to be used.